Xero and different APIs
I've been using Accounting API in my app with OAuth2.  Now I will need to use Finance API and possibly other APIs in the future.  Will I need to connect to different APIs separately or will I only have to connect once and get access to all APIs after getting access token to one of them?
Thanks.
I've looked up Xero documentation but could not find an answer.

When you want to access a different unrestricted API such as the Files, Projects Payroll and Assets APIs you need to add the new scopes to your authorisation link and then you would need to go through the connection steps again to add the new scopes to the access token.
The finance, bank feeds and XPM APIs are restricted so you would need to apply for your app to have access to the relevant scopes before you can go through the above steps.

Can I add all scopes I need in Accounting and Finance APIs in the beginning and make
one connection?

Technically you can add all the scopes you need in one request but if you haven't gone through the process to get your app assigned the finance API scopes you can't use these
